# Newrelic startup exception

Tags: java, tomcat, newrelic

We are getting the following error in catalina.out file when we restart our application with newrelic java agent configured.

We have followed the steps specified in newrelic installation guide and following is the entry created in catalina.sh by newrelic installer:

```
# ---- New Relic switch automatically added to start command on 2013 Dec 09, 20:24:35
NR_JAR=/usr/share/fk-ops-tomcat6-base/newrelic/newrelic.jar; export NR_JAR
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$NR_JAR"; export JAVA_OPTS
```

Exception on app restart in catalina.out:

```
Error bootstrapping New Relic agent: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapLoader.load(BootstrapLoader.java:95)
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.premain(BootstrapAgent.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828)
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapLoader.getJarFileInAgent(BootstrapLoader.java:81)
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapLoader.addBridgeJarToClassPath(BootstrapLoader.java:47)
        at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapLoader.load(BootstrapLoader.java:92)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: Is the newrelic.yml placed and marked readable in the same directory as the .jar ?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem. The not very helpful error message alluded to the fact that the newrelic agent (or rather the user under which my server is running) wasn't able to write into /tmp. Maybe that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I hit that exception with that stack trace recently, and in my case it was caused by the temporary directory not existing at all.

In particular: by default tomcat uses `$CATALINA_BASE/temp` as value for the `java.io.tmpdir` property, and seems to create that when needed. At the time the newrelic agent boots up however it may not yet exist, and so newrelic agent fails with that exception.

After restarting things are fine (now the directory exists!), but I solved in my startup scripts:
1. set the value of `CATALINA_TMPDIR` explicitly to something I control
2. ensure that directory exists before starting tomcat.

Comment: yep, add "set CATALINA_TMPDIR=N:/tmp" in catalina.bat if you are using catalina.bat for startup and tomcat is in access restriced place like C:\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the newrelic.yml placed and marked readable in the same directory as the .jar

Comment: Both newrelic.jar and newrelic.yml are in the same directory which 777 permissions set on parent directory as well as individual files.

Answer (score 0):

I work for New Relic.

As you've seen from the answers above, there can be multiple causes for this kind of message - some of which are pretty unexpected.  Since this forum is not intended for back-and-forth messaging about incidents, in case neither of the previous two answers solved the problem for you, your best bet will be to open a ticket for support at http://support.newrelic.com where we can ask to look at your logfile and gather debug logs as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using apache version 6.0.33.  Once I upgraded to 7.0.53 everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

save problem.
But I found this:

```
Sep 09, 2015 11:19:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /mnt/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/temp
```

then doing this:

```
mkdir /mnt/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/temp
cp /mnt/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/newrelic/* /mnt/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/temp
```

Everything works.
You may not need cp.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at very early of Tomcat log (catalina.out) after NewRelic exception, you can see what folder is required that are missing. Here is mine:

```
May 29, 2017 5:04:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /var/log/tomcat/tomcat7/temp
May 29, 2017 5:04:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
```

Hope this help